# How to add javadoc for android to Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

I just started using Net Beans.  I am wanting to try my hand at developing android apps.  I got the android sdk downloaded and everything is working well.  I can create little apps and run them in the emulator.  However, the intelisense popup for the android methods says that the Javadoc isn't found.  Is there a way to add it?

Answer (score 5):

The best way as below steps in NetBeans 7:

1. Tools --> Ant Libraries.
2. New library --> Name it Android.
3. Classpath --> Add JAR/Folder --> {SDK Folder}\platforms\android-16\android.jar
   (in short find android.jar and use it's path, for me I'm using 16 version).
4. Javadoc --> Add ZIP/Folder --> {SDK Folder}\docs\references
   (important note: you may get error in above step, so search will not work. To solve it, copy the file index.html inside [references folder] to a new file and called index-all.html. Then re-add the path in step 4).

Source: [Here](http://markalcalaramos.blogspot.com/2010/04/android-development-netbeans-free-form.html)

Comment: Note that for this to work, you will need to have the "Documentation for Android SDK" package installed (using the Android SDK Manager).

Comment: Step 4 worked for me without the workaround, though the error was shown (Netbeans 8.1).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Android Sources provided by [adt-addons](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/).  This eclipse plugin will download all of the sources and attach them automatically.

If you aren't using Eclipse, you can still download the source zips from the jar at http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/plugins/

Extract the jar file and inside you'll find source zips for each platform revision. Attach these to your IDE.

Otherwise, you can check out the sources manually from git but this is a rather lengthy and arduous process to achieve the above.

Comment: thanks! ive already downloaded the documentation, but the problem with android plugin for netbeans is that it doesnt let you attach sources or javadoc for the android plataforms added... But if you refer to adding a new source folder to my projects, wouldn't that make netbeans compile all the sources there every time i make a clean/build of my poject?

Comment: I usually use Eclipse for Android dev but I've just had a look, as I am a big Netbeans fan. Are you using the nbandroid plugin (http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/pages/Install) as suggested by http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans? For me, once I have added the platforms I can see the android.jar in Libraries, and I get javadocs.

Comment: My bad. I moved my "docs" folder inside /android-sdk-windows/ and now everything  works as expected. Seems that nbandroid want it to be there and dont allow us to manually link the docs to the plataform. Wich is a good decision as there is only one doc shared by all android platforms. Thanks! (Accepting bounty as the answer is in this post)

Comment: That's great - my docs folder was already in the right place but glad you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your setup is like, but the JavaDoc is stored in */docs/reference*
For my setup I had to create a zip of that folder and add it as JavaDoc to the Android library.

Answer (score 0):

You can download various javadocs from

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/com/google/android/android/2.3.3/

Just drop the javadocs jar files to android-sdk-{macosx,windows,linux}/docs

Answer (score 0):

If you use the nbandroidsupport plugin you can download the javadoc from Android SDK Manager, you can found the package in the latest android's API (in my case Android 5.1.1) the name of package is "Documentation for Android SDK".

Once you have installed the package restart your netbeans. In my case the javadoc is not showing sometimes pressing `ctrl+space` on the method therefore you can show the javadoc pressing `ctrl+shift+space`.

Note: this method applies to any API version.