# How to add javadoc for android (R16) to Netbeans 7.x

Tags: android, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 and am trying to develop an android app.

After reading this with no avail:
[How to add javadoc for android to Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321007/how-to-add-javadoc-for-android-to-netbeans)

My question is about my javadoc location.

I am taking them from:
android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-10\docs\reference\
and putting them in:
android-sdk-windows\docs folder.

I tried with and without the refrence folder.

I am always getting that I don't have javadoc:
[image: JavaDoc Missing]

If I press right click on the GoogleAPI located in the project library I can see that the words Show JavaDoc are grayed out:
[image: grayed out]

Is this correct?
If not what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grayed out is still grayed out but I have javadoc now.
What I did was install the documantation that comes with API15 and not putting them manually.
That solved my problem.